# Web Browser Win form control login register an app with facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, facebook-login, autologin

I am using a Web Browser control for a win form application.

I am trying to register an application throw Facebook login\app registation.

My problem is that first the authentication process pops up the login then a chin of redirects occurs that I cant seem to follow...

has any one done that?

an example process can be viewed when trying to login to INetGiant here:

http://www.inetgiant.com/user/login

How do I do it?

Here is some code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Grabs an add from the ad table.
    /// </summary>
    private void GrabAnAdFromTheAdsTableAndHrefToLoginInFacebook()
    {
        HtmlElement adTd = Document.GetElementFromPoint(FirstAdPosition);

        AdContent = adTd.InnerHtml;

        ProcessBrowser.Navigate(Resources.FacebookLoginURL);
    }

    private void LoginToFacebook()
    {
        HtmlElement form = Document.GetElementById("login_form");

        if (form == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        HtmlElement email = Document.GetElementById("email");
        HtmlElement password = Document.GetElementById("pass");

        if (email != null)
        {
            email.SetAttribute("value", this.UserNameForFacebook);
        }

        if (password != null)
        {
            password.SetAttribute("value", this.PasswordForFacebook);
        }

        form.InvokeMember("submit");
    }


    private void LoginToFacebookAndHrefToLoginInInetGiant()
    {
        LoginToFacebook();

        if (!_beforeRegisterToInetGiantWithFacebook)
        {
            LoadingTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnFacebookLoginPageLoad);
            LoadingTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void OnFacebookLoginPageLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadingTimer.Stop();
        LoadingTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(OnFacebookLoginPageLoad);
        LoadingTimer.Enabled = false;

        ProcessBrowser.Navigate(Resources.InetgiantLoginURL);
    }
```

Comment: how about posting your code sample here not everyone will go to some random site to create a user profile just to see the code or sample of what you are trying to accomplish..
Please show how you are trying to connect i.e username / PW sites like those rely on Credentials thanks

Comment: I am trying to find a way to do it... The facebook app registration process involves steps that I cannot hack into with the Web Browser control.